Auto Click VBA needed for Text Box in Slideshow mode
I am an occupational therapist, and I am trying to create a typing program for children using PowerPoint.
I have a vba for shuffling slides and I have a vba to move onto the next slide once the correct letter has typed.
My issue is that the user needs to click on the text box on each slide manually, and for some of the children I work with that would make things to complicated to understand.
I have put a post on /answers.microsoft.com, I have been given the code to move on when the correct key is selected:
Private Sub TextBox1_Change() 
    Dim lSlideIndex As Long 
    If TextBox1.Text = "X" Then 
        lSlideIndex = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex 
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (lSlideIndex + 1) 
    End If 
End Sub

Although there seems to be some issues with this code when using it with the shuffle slide code:
Sub ShuffleSlides()
FirstSlide = 2
LastSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

Randomize

For i = FirstSlide To LastSlide
    RSN = Int((LastSlide - FirstSlide + 1) * Rnd + FirstSlide)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).MoveTo (RSN)
Next i
End Sub

But the main thing I am looking for is a code to auto select the text box, could anyone help with that?
Thank you!

You wrote: "Although there seems to be some issues with this code when using it with the shuffle slide code:"  What issues? It's hard to fix something when you know what that something IS.  As far as auto-selecting the text box, you can't, at least not if you're in slideshow view. You can't select anything in slide show view.



when you know what that -- make that "don't know".  Sorry.



So for the issue, it is just that when the 'move to the next slide' code is added it seems to  skip a bunch of slides. I think it is because the code doesn't know that the slides are shuffled but I am not 100% sure. Regarding the auto select, there is a text box on the developer section (its a small box with 'ab' in it, and when the mouse is over it is says 'text box (activeX control) - insert a text box control'). And that text box can be selected in slideshow view, and I was wondering if that could be automatically selected?

Yes, I understood what type of text box you were talking about; that's the only kind that allows you to enter text while in slide show mode. But again, you can't select anything in slide show mode and the text box control doesn't have a method for setting focus to it (though the similar control on a userform does; see my reply elsewhere).

I am a little confused, this might be another obvious question. But you are saying we can't select on a slide show, but my problem is that I have to move the mouse and select the text box because it does not select it automatically. Do you just mean you can't select in slide show with a vba? But if that text box doesn't have a way of being focused on with vba I guess it is a lost cause. Also what is a userform and could that be used to help with my issue? Thank you for all your help by the way.

Sorry if I was using "select" in a very PPT-specific way. In slide show view, you can't select shapes as you can in normal view, though ActiveX shapes (like your text box) have special properties; that allows you, for instance, to click INTO the text box, though not select it and move it around in slide show view. A user form is a way of creating an application-like dialog box. If you're new to VBA, it's not something I'd attack.

Okay, so is there a way of creating a code that would click into the ActiveX Text Box automatically in the slideshow, so that the user would not need to click into it themselves?

If I knew of such a thing, I'd have told you about it umpteen messages ago.  :-)
